# Populating values from one textbox to another

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<input type="text" class="formtext" id="t${status.index}" 
       name="List.lItemList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.value1" 
       value="0.0"
       onChange="validateOnChange(this,'desc','minvalue','maxValue','float')" 
       onKeyUp = "document.getElementById('t${status.index+1}').value=this.value">  

 <input type="text" class="formtext" id="t${status.index+1}"              
        name="List.clItemList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.value2"
        value="0.0"
        onChange="validateOnChange(this,'desc','minvalue','maxvalue','float')">
```

In the above code I have two text boxes in a particular row:

> 1st row:  textbox1 textbox2
> 2nd row:  textbox3 textbox4

When I enter the value in one of the textboxes , it needs to be copied to other textbox simultaneously. So I am using an `KeyUp` event to update the textbox. But the ID for each textbox is giving issues. Regardless of which textbox I update, only textbox2 is updated. I want it to be updated based on the row.

```
Ex = For each itemlist[i] { 
    Input type(id = status.index[i] onkeyup) 
    input type(id = status.index[i]+1 update the value entered on the 1st textbox ) 
} repeat
```

Comment: -1 for asking the same question twice within 30 minutes. Even if you do not get an answer on the first one, you don't have to repost.

Comment: Sorry i am new bie to this forum.Doesnt know the rules Will delete the older post.

Comment: Hi everyone , kindly add in the comment if anything is unclear.Thanks for the timely help.....

Comment: What does the *generated* HTML look like? What is the meaning of the pseudo code at the bottom of your question?

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyUp = "this.form[this.name.replace('value1','value2')].value=this.value"`

in case you delete the other one